Tunnel Mole not giving urls
After running "tmole 3000" in windows cmd as admin I'm no getting an answer.I'm just getting nothing instead tmole image.
I'm hopping to get urls but nothing happened, is not even giving an error. The .exe is in the right place.
I also tried installing it with npm, but same results

Please do no use images but rather the text of the error you have.

Universal Installer Windows
curl -O https://install.tunnelmole.com/n3d5g/install && sudo bash install

Windows executable

Download tmole.exe
Put it somewhere in your PATH.

Source: https://tunnelmole.com/docs/

Please let me know the update about the given solution
